# How load template from another App through Main App

Tags: django

I just started learn Django and got a problem. I have a Main App, that must include another apps. My Main app has url  localhost: port/main/. I have main template, which consist header, content and footer. In header I load Menu. How load News template in content block, when url will localhost: port/main/news. I use CBV.

Comment: please add more info and code example so the community can better help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your main template has surely a content block, something like

```
{% block content %}

{% endblock content %}
```

The news template should use the same block like:

```
{% extends 'main.html' %}
{% block content %}
    here the content of your news.html template
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: I know this solution, but when I use url, I call to View Class get function, where I load some objects from database. Now, I use Ajax location hash. When user push button, for example News, I send query to localhost: port/news and get response that I load to content div. but I would like to avoid using it.